# Running into a problem setting up my database

Tags: python, sql

I'm doing a project for CS50x, where the goal is to create a basic stock trading website, and one of the functions to be implemented is an option to buy stocks.

I have a database, with two tables. One (users) is a table with ID, username, passwordhash, and cash. The other table (stocks) should contain the same ID as in users, then a stock symbol, and then an amount of stocks, so: id, symbol, amount.

What I did was:

```
CREATE TABLE stocks(
    id INTEGER, 
    symbol VARCHAR(10),
    amount INTEGER,
    PRIMARY KEY (id), 
    FOREIGN KEY (id) 
        REFERENCES users (id) 
        ON DELETE CASCADE 
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION);
```

However, now when I in my Python code run the code to insert the bought stocks into this table, I run into a problem:

```
ValueError: UNIQUE constraint failed: stocks.id
```

ID has to be unique, so I can't insert more buy more than 1 different stock with one user account. How do I create a table where the ID is still linked to the ID in the users table, however I can still add multiple different stocks under one ID?

Comment: In general, the `id` should be internal to the database and generated automatically, rather than passed in when a row is created.

Comment: So would this be better?:

`CREATE TABLE stocks(id INTEGER, user_id INTEGER, symbol VARCHAR(10), amount INTEGER, PRIMARY KEY (id), FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users (id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION);`

Answer (score 0):

I would attempt this I've got a similar table and it works fine for me just make sure to specify your foreign key with _fk just to make it easier to notice what it is

```
 CREATE TABLE `sites` (
 `id` int(225) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `userID_fk` int(255) NOT NULL,
 `amount` int(500) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `userID_fk` (`userID_fk`),
 CONSTRAINT `stocks_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`userID_fk`) REFERENCES `users` (`userID`) ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT
```

hope that works for you